# Create an ID number based off form fields - Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have built an excel VBA form which is able to generate a unique ID number based on: the "record number" (i.e. how many non-null cells in a range), a  letter or letters, the financial year (i.e. 17,for financial year 2016/17), and another letter.

The code, financial year, and other letter are all based on inputs from the user, and the number is obviously auto generated, resulting in a code in the following format: 001-A17S

below is the excel code to yield the above result:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Worksheets("Project Tracking").Activate

DeliveryPartnerCode = lbl_DeliveryPartnerCode
FinancialyearString = txt_FinancialYear.Text
Financialyear = Right(FinancialyearString, 2)

nonfilledCells = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A5:A100"))
AWRNumber = nonfilledCells + 1
AWRNumberstring = CStr(AWRNumber)

If (AWRNumber < 9) Then
    AWRPrefix = "00"
ElseIf (AWRNumber < 99) Then
    AWRPrefix = "0"
Else
    AWRPrefix = ""
End If


If cmb_State.ListIndex = 0 Then
    State = "S"
ElseIf cmb_State.ListIndex = 1 Then
    State = "N"
ElseIf cmb_State.ListIndex = 2 Then
    State = "Q"
ElseIf cmb_State.ListIndex = 3 Then
    State = "V"
ElseIf cmb_State.ListIndex = 4 Then
    State = "A"
End If



lbl_AWRReference = AWRPrefix & AWRNumberstring & "-" & DeliveryPartnerCode & Financialyear & State
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This bastardised excel spreadsheet is no longer appropriate for our use, and I've decided to create a proper database in Access.

I have set up a table with the appropriate columns (Autonumber with a mask of 000), a textbox for the financial year, and drop down boxes for the code and the last letter. but I've got no idea now how to concatenate all this together to give the right format, the place the result into a textbox on the form. I can't use expression builder (doesn't let me pick the autonumber), and I can't find the syntax or logic for writing a VBA code to perform a similar calculation like the excel VBA code above.

What is the best way to achieve what I am looking for? I will admit it has been over 5 years since I've played with Access, so I am a bit fuzzy :P

Thanks.

Comment: You should never use Autonumber for tasks like this. Search SO for _Custom Autonumber_ - lots of hits.

Comment: Are you trying to store this or simply display it (You shouldn't store it if it can simply be calculated) ? To display it on a form I would create it in the underlying forms query. and finally and most importantly - What have you tried ?

Comment: @Gustav I now appreciate that, however, i'm still not sure on how to get a DMax calculated number, and other data that the user provides into the format required - do you have any advice

Comment: @Minty I am storing it as the project ID number will be used to link people, proposal documents etc all back to the one project using this number, which is calculated based on certain information about the project. I've tried expression builder, concatenating etc. I would ideally like to do this through VBA but I'm unsure about the syntax needed, and the way to call the code once written

Comment: To be honest you are causing yourself pain. You have a unique number per project in your autonumber field. Use this as the master linking ID. If you want to create a important looking reference for putting on the heading of a document then simply concatenate it. A simple numeric primary key has many advantages. To answer you question this format should work; lbl_AWRReference = AWRPrefix & AWRNumberstring & "-" & DeliveryPartnerCode & Financialyear & State . If it doesn't please post up the VBA you have tried and the error or results you are getting.

Comment: thanks @Minty - that approach works for what I need. if you want to copy and past that into the answer field, ill give it a big green tick! :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lbl_AWRReference = AWRPrefix & AWRNumberstring & "-" & DeliveryPartnerCode & Financialyear & State .
```

Glad you have it working.